# How to obtain PDF version of report using Django reporting

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Using `Django_reporting-0.21-py2.7` I am able to view the reports and able to download reports as a CSV file. Is there someway I can get the same report in PDF format (preferably via the Django Admin page)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [xhtml2pdf](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xhtml2pdf/) to convert your report to PDF format. Also you can find more information about outputting-pdf in django [here in django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-pdf/).